# Could not normalize path for file '\ …'1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

here i add more information ! i have met this question when i import the project into the Android Studio! Could you help me to make it think you very much!`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

```
     Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize path for file '\\ ...'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.normalise(AbstractFileResolver.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.convertObjectToURI(AbstractFileResolver.java:177)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolveUri(AbstractFileResolver.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.getUrl(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated.getUrl(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createRealResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ResolveIvyFactory.create(ResolveIvyFactory.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.createComponentSource(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.access$100(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
... 83 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.normalise(AbstractFileResolver.java:98)
... 112 more
```

here is the gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

   android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
      useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "io.itit.ititeducation"
      minSdkVersion 19
      targetSdkVersion 21

      versionCode 43
      versionName "1.5.3"
    }
   buildTypes {
      debug {
        // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
     }
     release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }

     android.applicationVariants.all {
         variant ->
        variant.outputs.each {
            output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "科达智慧教育_io.itit.ititeducation_v"
                        + defaultConfig.versionName + "_" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk");
        }
}

    dexOptions {
       maxProcessCount 8
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }
    compileOptions {
       targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
   }

 repositories {
    maven { url '// ...' }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
     }
  }



dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
compile files('libs/jg_filter_sdk_1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/wup-1.0.0.E-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('libs/Xg_sdk_v2.42_20160111_1539.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8'
compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'me.imid.swipebacklayout.lib:library:1.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'cn.trinea.android.common:trinea-android-common:4.2.15'
compile 'com.github.orhanobut:logger:1.12'
compile 'org.xutils:xutils:3.3.25'
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
compile 'com.romainpiel.shimmer:library:1.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.10@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.qiujuer:genius:2.4.0'
compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
compile 'com.github.dexafree:materiallist:3.2.+'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.3'
compile 'com.liulishuo.filedownloader:library:0.2.0'
compile 'com.duwei.pinwheel:pinwheel:0.1'
compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.github.panwrona:DownloadProgressBar:1.1'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile files('libs/photo_library.jar')
compile files('libs/videocache.jar')
compile project(':videolib')
compile project(':itit_lib')
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

the other

```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

the other three modules

1

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 dependencies {
 }

  android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
  }
  sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }

   }

}
```

2

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
     apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

     android {
         compileSdkVersion 23
          buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
          useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 19
           targetSdkVersion 21
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.1"
        }
       buildTypes {
          release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
       compileOptions {
           targetCompatibility 1.8
           sourceCompatibility 1.8
       }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.8'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.github.lazylibrary:lazylibrary:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.orhanobut:logger:1.12'
    compile 'cn.trinea.android.common:trinea-android-common:4.2.15'
    compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8'
    compile 'com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.10@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':videolib')
   }
```

3

```
 apply plugin: 'java'

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'
 }
```

Comment: try changing target sdk version to 23

Comment: I have change all target  but it don't resolve it

Answer (score 0):

remove "maven { url '// ...' }" line from your build.gradle

```
     repositories {
    **maven { url '// ...' }**
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
     }
  }
```

Comment: if  the problem solved. Accept this answer ( click the ✔ next to answer)